# What should you do if an officer leaves a traffic stop?

Tags: united-states, police, traffic, oregon

This might be a bit of a TV trope, but I think it happens in reality as well. Suppose an officer pulls someone over for a traffic infraction and starts talking to the person about why they were pulled over. Suddenly, a much more urgent call comes out over the officer's radio, and the officer speeds off in their cruiser without giving any instructions to the person the officer had pulled over - the officer didn't say "wait here," "move along," or anything else.

What is the person who was pulled over supposed to do?

If they leave, I worry that this could be seen as an act of eluding, but if they stay, I worry that the officer might simply never return.

Answer (score 1):

It takes the officer seconds to say "stay here" or "you can leave". It's more likely that the motorist misheard.

Call 911 from your cell phone or nearest phone and ask for instructions. The call taker can contact dispatch who can raise the officer on the radio. They will also take down your information as part of any 911 call, specifically name and phone number, so the police can contact you again if necessary.

The call will be recorded so if there's ever a dispute about fleeing, you will have the instructions given to you as evidence.